# Blazor Server run only one background task

Tags: c#, .net, blazor-server-side, backgroundworker, ihostedservice

I have a Blazor Server application (net 7) where a long running background task can be triggered by any user, but once the task has been started everyone must wait until that task is completed.

The users visit a Razor page then leave the page and maybe log-off, but the background task should keep running.

So I need some kind of static background task which updates the UI (via [IProgress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=net-7.0) or something) when someone visits the page and also is only allowed to be triggered once. Sounds like a classic singleton Task, but is that right here?

I know of [IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) but I don't need a queue of Jobs to be consumed infinitely, only one single task static task running in background and showing each user who visits a Razor page what the current status of the task is.

[Update 1] Just for clarification, it is not a very long running task, still the behavior should be as described.

Comment: You shouldn't run long-running tasks in your web server. I'd recommend offloading long-running tasks to a dedicated service running in something like an Azure function app or an AWS lambda.

Comment: Why not register a class service (say MyTaskService) as a singleton ?

Comment: @auburg That might actually be not a bad idea. I could just create a singleton service with a property `public event Action OnChange` to subscribe to for updated for every page load.

Comment: You may want to encapsulate this service via a separate Asp.Net WebApi (through your Blazor back-end)

Comment: @auburg I know what you mean, but why should I? Sounds a little over-engineering.